# Scaling an image proportionally

Tags: html, css, image

Let's say I want to target the Sun in this image

http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/planets-590x330.jpg

[image]

```css
#graphic .image {
    position: absolute; 
    background: url("http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/planets-590x330.jpg")
    }
#graphic #sun {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.image {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="graphic">
  <div class="image" id="sun"></div>
  </div>
```

Let’s say I have a canvas of 500 x 500
I have an asset 50px from the top, 0 from the left
To target it, I will do a background-position: 0px 50px right?

Problem is if the image is 100x100, I want it to fit a 50x50, it will just crop half of the image

How can I scale it down proportionally and make it fit inside 50x50 while not being cropped out?

Comment: [developer.mozilla.org - Scaling background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images)

Comment: The sun is not `100 x 100`, but it is `590 x 330`

Comment: You can't make that you want. You can't know how many pixels the sun is occuping, to reduce proportionally the image, only with CSS is impossible.

Comment: The Sun is actually 72x68, 590x330 is the entire image

Comment: Let’s say I have a canvas of 500x500
I have an asset 50px from the top, 0 from the left
To target it, I will do a background-position: 0px 50px right?

Problem is if the image is 100x100, I want it to fit a 50x50, it will just crop half of the image

Comment: You can't know dimensions in CSS. You need another language to know the exact dimensions (javascript, php, etc), and work with them.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use something like this:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: url('http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/planets-590x330.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: 300px;
  background-size: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

Keeping the `background-size: 300px` does the trick.

Comment: Yes, but only if you know the size of the image and where are the points you need

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude This is something similar to CSS Sprites buddy... `:)`

Comment: Yes but I think that OP needs something more than this. I suspect... :)

Comment: Let them speak... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/203/

CSS

```
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: url('http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/planets-590x330.jpg');
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: 250px;
}
```